# Can I describe myself as "self-teaching" instead of "self-taught"?

Tags: adjectives

I am learning sculpting by myself and this is an *ongoing* process. So, I'm going to describe myself as a "self-teaching" rather than a "self-taught" sculptor, since it seems to me that the latter describes someone who has already learned the majority of the techniques of the field. But I have not seen anyone using "self-teaching."

Is "self-teaching" correct? Doesn't it sound weird?

Comment: It's not an existing expression, but if you explain it when you use it the sense is clear enough.

Comment: That's basically the meaning of _autodidact_, which you can drop whenever you want. It tends to stop conversation.

Comment: @JohnLawler you mean *autodidact* is more common? Why stop?

Comment: No, it's not a common word, but that is what it means -- somebody who teaches themself, thus being both self-teaching and self-taught. Though one implies the other.

Comment: @N.S. What reveals this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+is+an+autodidact%2Che+is+self+taught&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) is quite surprising in the light of the  assertion found above concerning stoppages in conversation, an assertion that sums up a rather expected state of affairs.

Comment: @JohnLawler Ahh... that's great thanks

Comment: The trouble with _self-teaching_ is that present participles (_-ing_ words) are generally active in meaning rather than passive. So it means "teacher of self". While this does imply that you are also the student, it puts more emphasis on you as teacher than as student.

Comment: "I'm teaching myself sculpture" would be the usual way of expressing it. But that's not an adjective. I think you can use "self-taught" after a certain point, even if you're still learning.

Comment: ' ... self-taught and still learning.'?

Answer (score 2):

*Self-teaching* would sound odd because it is usually not applied to an individual as a descriptor. Rather, it is usually used to describe the action of learning on your own.

To help break that down, I have sampled both *self-teaching* and *self-taught* in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/). Originally I did a compare search, but I didn't get much useful info, so I searched each individually.

Self-teaching has 35 results. Zero of the results used *self-teaching* to directly describe an individual (e.g., "I am a self-teaching X" or "she is self-teaching." Instead, examples did the following:

- Precede a noun referring to a module, tool, style, or other inanimate noun: "self-teaching style," "self-teaching tools," "self-teaching manuals"
- Follow a preposition, describing an action: "Get in the habit of self-teaching," "he's a self-proclaimed autodidact who learns best through self-teaching," "their learning came from self-teaching"
- Otherwise describe the action of teaching, functioning as a noun: "it's basically self-teaching," "Self-teaching is pretty much the entire experience of debugging a program"

Self-taught has 890 results. Many of the results use *self-taught* to directly describe an individual. These are culled from the first ten or so results:

> She brings the perspective of a **self-taught knitter** to her books and classes

> I'm **self-taught** in electronics, software, mechanics, protocols, music, and so much more

> **self-taught** composer

> **self-taught** Graphic Designer

> **self-taught** rebel

> **self-taught** sportsman

> 40-year-old blind, **self-taught** lawyer

A *self-taught* person, or a person who is self-taught, is a stock turn of phrase. It's expected. *Self-teaching*, in contrast, is mainly used to describe the action itself. You could in theory describe yourself as a *self-teaching sculptor*, but people wouldn't have the handholds of an expected idiom to make sense of that phrase.

Comment: This doesn't really address the OP's concern (which I kinda share) that calling oneself a *self-taught sculptor* implies that the learning is behind them.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat It provides research largely confirming that 'describ[ing] myself as a "self-teaching" rather than a "self-taught" sculptor' will sound off-kilter.